# What is the name of this type of math problem?

Tags: algorithms

I'm a computer programmer not a math guy and I have this problem I'm trying to solve and I don't even know what the name of the math problem is that I can look up to help me solve my problem. I was hoping you could help me.

I have an amount of storage available and some of that storage refers to the available storage in that total amount of storage as a lookup table.

I know how much space the lookup information takes up per amount of storage but I don't know how to figure out how much information I can actually store total given that some of the total has to be used for the look up information. I know I can Brute Force guess a number and then adjust back and forth in a loop until it comes up with the optimal answer, but I'm pretty sure there's a math formula way of working this out without looping and it's not simple algebra and I just don't know what it's called. If anybody has an idea I can go look it up. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $N$ be the size of the total storage, let $L$ be the storage size of the lookup table, let $S$ be the amount of available storage (excluding the lookup table) and let $\alpha>0$ be the fraction of how much space the lookup information $L$ takes up per amount of storage $S$.

Then your problem can be expressed by this system of equations:

$$\begin{cases} L + S = N \\ L = \alpha S\end{cases}$$

This is solved by

$$\begin{cases} S = \frac{1}{1+\alpha}N \\ L = \frac{\alpha}{1+\alpha} N\end{cases}$$

This is not really advanced math, this is just linear algebra.

Comment: Well that's the problem,  I don't know what S is. S depends on the number of entries in the lookup table, and the number of entries in the lookup table depends on how much free space there is after the look up table for storage space. So the more storage space the bigger look up table the bigger the look up table the less space there is for storage. So they each depend on each other and I'm not sure how to determine what the optimal split split point is.

Comment: I figure there's a name for this type of problem but I'm not sure what it is called to research it.

Comment: Oh wait. I think I get what you're saying.  One moment. Really not a math guy. :-)

Comment: Okay I think I get what you're saying now. I misunderstood on first read. I give that a go thanks.

Comment: okay, I get it, I see what you did there. It is absurdly simple now that I've played with it. I didn't think of α as a fraction, I only saw it as a count of bytes, but yeah, once you place it in relation to the whole thing, makes a lot of sense, thanks.